# getelementsbyname not working on diffrnrt web

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyname

Good day to all.
I'm new here, so I apologize if I do something wrong.

What I'm trying to do ... I'm trying to create a Bat file that would automatically open a specific site and enter there login and password, nadimal "Login" ... Emulation of what I attended today on this site ...
In the past, I did it quite well ...
Here is an example. (Login and password changed)

```html
@set @script=0 /*
@echo off
set @script=
@cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~dpnx0"
@exit /b
*/
 
var url,login,password;
url      = "http://elearn2.mbschool.ru/lmsonline/index.jsp";
// заменить на свои учетные данные
login    = "k";
password = "gx";
 
var IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
IE.visible = 1;
IE.navigate(url); 
 
while (IE.Busy) {
  WScript.Sleep(200);
}
 
IE.document.getElementsByName("user")(0).value = login;
IE.document.getElementsByName("password")(0).value = password;
button = IE.document.getElementsByName("save")(0);
button.focus();
button.click();
```

A little time has passed and the developers have made changes to the site ...
For the moment, such an algorithm does not work for some reason

```html
@set @script=0 /*
@echo off
set @script=
@cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~dpnx0"
@exit /b
*/
 
var url,login,password;
url      = "http://lms.mba.ru/mira/#&step=1&s=tT79vdH8nG0XWayfK0Lq&type=login&doaction=Go";
// заменить на свои учетные данные
login    = "k;
password = "6m";
 
var IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
//IE.visible = 0;
IE.navigate(url); 
IE.visible = 1;
 
while (IE.Busy) {
  WScript.Sleep(4000);
}

IE.document.getElementsByName("user")(0).value= login;
IE.document.getElementsByName("password")(0).value = password;
button = IE.document.getElementsByName("doaction")(0);
button.focus();
button.click();
```

For some reason, the login and password do not appear in the forms and the button is not pressed ...
Help me please.
Thank you.

Comment: So... no one can't help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had looked at the page's source code, you would have seen that the user and password text boxes are inside of an iframe. To manipulate DOM elements inside of an iframe, you need to load the content first.

```
@set @script=0 /*
@echo off
set @script=
@cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~dpnx0"
@exit /b
*/

var url,login,password;
url      = "http://lms.mba.ru/mira/#&step=1&s=tT79vdH8nG0XWayfK0Lq&type=login&doaction=Go";

login    = "k";
password = "6m";

var IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
//IE.visible = 0;
IE.visible = 1;
IE.navigate(url); 

while (IE.Busy) {
  WScript.Sleep(4000);
}

IE.document.getElementsByClassName("mira-frame-content")[0].contentDocument.getElementsByName('user')[0].value= login;
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("mira-frame-content")[0].contentDocument.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = password;
button = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("mira-frame-content")[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];
button.focus();
button.click();
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I try your code, bur it nor working too... there is nothing on page after codeworking... Can you help more. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, forgot the last three lines. Fixed. (And if you're saying that the text boxes don't get filled; that's ridiculous. I ran it on my machine to make sure it works before I posted it.) Also, your old code should work if you use Firefox or Chrome instead of Internet Explorer.

Comment: How can I use other browser  if there is `'var IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application");`

Comment: Ditch the batch script idea entirely and just use Greasemonkey; you won't need pesky things like a `InternetExplorer.Application`.

Comment: Tell me please. What is your version of IE? Maybe this is the problem? Also I want to say that in order for my first code to work, I had to specify in IE properties this site as "Local Intranet" in Bezovansnosti .... I tried with the second site to do so, but the code continues to fail. And I need IE. Help, maybe there are ideas? I have IE version 11

Comment: I'm also using IE 11.1066.14393.0 And [it works fine on my machine](http://i.imgur.com/JI9wdVk.gifv). At this point, all I can recommend is that you hit F12 and play around with the Javascript console until you find something that works; that's what I had to do.

Comment: Dear friend. I find a problem and now it's working. BUT! The button is not in focus and not working on click! You can understand it because you variant of script has no message about error of login/password like this... [link](https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/04/790df386157ae0774baa3b2c36b19bc0.png) Can you help me more?

Comment: Looks like the button was its own separate element. I've updated the code.